# Retrieve information from Google GCP Project Credentials API key

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-oauth, google-cloud-iam

What information can you retrieve from Google's API Key created through Google GCP Console.

GCP Console -> Menu -> APIs & Services -> Credentials -> API Key

Is there a way on the backend to get the project id associated to this  query string ex: key=apiKey?
or
list all API keys for a GCP project using some googleAPI?
or
something like: gcloud iam api-keys list?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

> What information can you retrieve from Google's API Key created
>   through Google GCP Console.

You can see information such as:

- API Key
- Creation date
- Created by
- Total usage
- Application Restrictions
- Website Restrictions

> Is there a way on the backend to get the project id associated to this
>   query string ex: key=apiKey?

Neither end-users nor GCP IAM members can see anything regarding the API Key except via the GCP Console.

> list all API keys for a GCP project using some googleAPI?

A public API has not been published for API Keys.

> something like: gcloud iam api-keys list?

No tools have been published that display information regarding API Keys.

Comment: Thanks John, so I can't verify or do much with this random string? Is it just for Google's use in Maps etc...?

Comment: Nothing, except to use it as an API Key for supported services.

Comment: John, thanks again, but how does this apply?  While API keys identify the calling project  OR  API keys allow the Extensible Service Proxy (ESP) to reject calls from projects that haven't been granted access or enabled in the API?  


  https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/when-why-api-key#api_keys_provide_project_authorization

Comment: @BrianB - I don't understand your comment.

Comment: It seems like with Google endpoints service they are talking about:  API keys provide
Project identification — Identify the application or the project that's making a call to this API  

If a project enables -MY- API I created in APIs & Services, creates an API key, calls my endpoint, is there no way for my to know what project is calling the API?

https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/when-why-api-key

Comment: I answered your comment in my answer. Google, of course, knows what project an API Key belongs to. You don't (programmatically) and there is no supported public interface to find out except for the Google Cloud Console.

Comment: The lack of ability to associate and retrieve other metadata associated with an API customer is, frankly, a HUGE product gap and is one of the many things that makes it difficult to defend the use of GCP. Since investment seems to be going into this product (eg API gateway) it would be helpful to share thinking behind why obvious things like project and other metadata arent available, if in fact that is a product decision, or timeline when they may be available. Cheers.

Comment: Ah, looks like there has been some movement! https://stackoverflow.com/a/62191049/6716781

Answer (score 1):

I believe `gcloud alpha services api-keys list` is what you are asking for? - https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/services/api-keys/list

Comment: Thanks Zaar, It's a good start, ideally I like to get more data (Name/Id/Org etc...) from the Api Key, and as an icing on the cake the ability to chargeback to the project would be fantastic.

Comment: Well, project number is part of the key name. A bit more info is availabe in `gcloud alpha services api-keys describe <key name>`